# Why I have to put all the script to index.html in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have used $.mobile.changepage to do the redirect in my phonegap+jquerymobile projects. However what makes me confused is that I need to put the script of all the pages to the same file index.html. If not, the redirect page can not execute the function in its header.

for example, my index.html seem to be 
`$(document).bind("deviceready",function(){$.mobile.changepage("test.html");})`

then, my device will redirect to test.html which seem to be

```
$("#btnTest").click(function(){alert("123");})
<button id="btnTest">Test</button>
```

However, the script will never execute in test.html. Then I put the script to index.html, what I expect to be is done. Whatever, if I put all the script to the same page, the project will become harder and harder to be preserved. Appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## Intro

This article can also be found **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** as a part of my blog.

## How jQuery Mobile handles page changes

To understand this situation you need to understand how jQuery Mobile works. It uses ajax to load other pages.

First page is loaded normally. Its **`HEAD`** and **`BODY`** is loaded into the **`DOM`**, and they are there to await other content. When second page is loaded, only its **`BODY`** content is loaded into the **`DOM`**. To be more precise, even **`BODY`** is not fully loaded. Only first div with an attribute data-role="page" will be loaded, everything else is going to be discarded. Even if you have more pages inside a **`BODY`** only first one is going to be loaded. This rule only applies to subsequent pages, if you have more pages in an initial **HTML** all of them will be loaded.

That's why your button is show successfully but click event is not working. Same click event whose parent **`HEAD`** was disregarded during the page transition.

Here's an official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Unfortunately you are not going to find this described in their documentation. Ether they think this is a common knowledge or they forgot to describe this like my other topics. (jQuery Mobile documentation is big but lacking many things).

## Solution 1

In your second page, and every other page, move your **`SCRIPT`** tag into the **`BODY`** content, like this:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        // And rest of your HTML content
        <script>
            // Your javascript will go here
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is a quick solution but still an ugly one.

Working example can be found in my other answer here: **[Pageshow not triggered after changepage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16083870/1848600)**

Another working example: [**Page loaded differently with jQuery-mobile transition**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430912/page-loaded-differently-with-jquery-mobile-transition/15431229#15431229)

## Solution 2

Move all of your javascript into the original first HTML. Collect everything and put it inside a single js file, into a **`HEAD`**. Initialize it after jQuery Mobile has been loaded.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="index.js"></script> // Put your code into a new file
</head>
```

In the end I will describe why this is a part of a good solution.

## Solution 3

Use **rel="external"** in your buttons and every elements you are using to change page. Because of it ajax is not going to be used for page loading and your jQuery Mobile app will behave like a normal web application. Unfortunately this is not a good solution in your case. Phonegap should never work as a normal web app.

```
<a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Next</a>
```

Official documentation, look for a chapter: **[Linking without Ajax](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)**

## Realistic solution

Realistic solution would use **Solution 2**. But unlike solution 2, I would use that same index.js file and initialize it inside a **`HEAD`** of every possible other page.

Now you can ask me **WHY**?

**`Phonegap`** like jQuery Mobile is buggy, and sooner or later there's going to be an error and your app will fail (including loaded DOM) if your every js content is inside a single HTML file. DOM could be erased and **`Phonegap`** will refresh your current page. If that page don't have javascript that it will not work until it is restarted.

## Final words

This problem can be easily fixed with a good page architecture. If anyone is interested I have wrote an **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)** about good jQuery Mobile page architecture. In a nut shell I am discussing that knowledge of how jQuery Mobile works is the most important thing you need to know before you can successfully create you first app.

Comment: quite a perfect answer! So our conclusion is that we can not separate every js file into every pages? That makes our app really hard to preserve. I am afraid whether it means a javascript bug would make the whole app down with JqueryMobile.

Comment: In solution 1, is it so ugly to include an external script file?

Comment: This is certainly not a bad idea, I prefer to have everything in an external files.

Comment: @Gajotres What's so ugly in Solution #1?

Comment: Script tag was always intended to be a part of HEAD, but event binding forced it to be used inside a BODY. This should be past now with delegated events but people for some reason still stick to old ways. Basically only ugly thing is an esthetic value of this solution.

Comment: OMG the hair pulling I could have avoided if I had read this first, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Unlike normal ordinary HTML pages, jQuery Mobile uses ajax technology when navigating between pages. So make sure to import all your JS files and libraries in all your html pages.

If you notice closely you will see that JS files from previous page is taken into consideration when loading the second page. But if you force rrefresh the current page then the js files of the current page will be effective.

So as I said earlier make sure to import the js files in all the html files.

Also no need to call `deviceready`, use following syntax to call your page specific js functions

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#YourPageID', function(){
    // Your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Mobile uses ajax to load a "page". A "page" here is a div with data-role=page. If you load a physical page index.html, you can navigate using changePage to any "page" div inside that page.

However, if you want to load a "page" from other physical page, jQM will only load the first "page" div from that page. What actually happen is you do not change page, jQM just load that particular "page" div using ajax and inject it to your current page.

You have two possible architecture where you put all your "pages" in a html page and navigate from there. Or you can have multiple page architecture. You can always mix this.

To physically change page, you need to add rel=external to your link.