# $(document).ready function won't fire up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm building a project made of several jquery mobile pages, each has a navbar.

when I view each page the $(document).ready function fires up well, but when I go to the page through the navbar it won't fire up.. also in the chrome debugger I see only one html page (the one I'm currently viewing) in the source folder.

when I refresh the page the function works ok

tried to replace the "$(document).ready(function () {" with:

"$("div[data-role*='page']").live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {" as someone suggested

but that doesn't work as well.

**that's the first page I load:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/TableCSSCode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {



            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.aspx/return_member_list",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (res) {

                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(res.d);
                    var tableStr = "<table class='CSSTableGenerator'>";

                    $.each(parsedData, function () {
                        tableStr += "<tr><td>" + this.fName + "</td><td>" + this.lName + "</td></tr>";
                    });
                    tableStr += "</table>";
                    $('#tableDiv').html(tableStr);


                },
                error: function (res, msg, code) {
                    // log the error to the console
                    alert("The following error occured: " + msg + " " + code);
                } //error

            });

        });


    </script>


</head> 
<body>
       <div id="page1" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                <h1>חברי העמותה</h1>
            </div> 

            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.htm">חברי העמותה</a></li>
                    <li><a href="build.htm">בניית צוות</a></li>
                    <li><a href="test.htm"> בדיקה</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="tableDiv"></div>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer">
                <h1>footer area</h1>
            </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**And below are the second and third page's head:** 
**build.htm:**

```
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/TableCSSCode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function save_crew()
        {

            p_num = new Object();
            p_num.p1 = p1.value;
            p_num.p2 = p2.value;
            p_num.p3 = p3.value;
            p_num.p4 = p4.value;

            l_num = new Object();
            l_num.l1 = l1.value;
            l_num.l2 = l2.value;
            l_num.l3 = l3.value;


            s_num = new Object();
            s_num.s1 = s1.value;
            s_num.s2 = s2.value;
            s_num.s3 = s3.value;



            var photo = { 'p1': p_num.p1, 'p2': p_num.p2, 'p3': p_num.p3, 'p4': p_num.p4 };
            var light = { 'l1': l_num.l1, 'l2': l_num.l2, 'l3': l_num.l3, 'l4': l_num.l4 };
            var sound = { 's1': s_num.s1, 's2': s_num.s2, 's3': s_num.s3, 's4': s_num.s4 };

            // Put the object into storage
            localStorage.setItem('photo', JSON.stringify(photo));
            localStorage.setItem('light', JSON.stringify(light));
            localStorage.setItem('sound', JSON.stringify(sound));

            // Retrieve the object from storage
            var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('sound');

            var ro = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

            alert(ro.s2);

            window.location.href="test.htm";

        }



    </script>


</head>
```

**test.htm:**

```
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="css/TableCSSCode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var sound_RO = localStorage.getItem('sound');
            var photo_RO = localStorage.getItem('photo');
            var light_RO = localStorage.getItem('light');

            sound_RO = JSON.parse(sound_RO);
            photo_RO = JSON.parse(photo_RO);
            light_RO = JSON.parse(light_RO);

            $.each(sound_RO, function (index, value) {
                alert(value);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getdata.aspx/return_prof",
                data: "{prof:'צלם'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

                success: function (res) {

                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(res.d);





                    $('[data-role="content"]').append('<div id="collapsible-set" data-role="collapsible-set"></div>');
                    $("#collapsible-set").append('<div id="collapsible" data-role="collapsible"></div>');
                    $("#collapsible").append('<h3>צלמים </h3>');

                    for (i = 0; parsedData[i] != null; i++) {

                        $("#collapsible").append('<p>' + parsedData[i].fName + ' ' + parsedData[i].lName + '</p>');

                    }

                    $('[data-role="content"]').trigger('create');







                },
                error: function (res, msg, code) {
                    // log the error to the console
                    alert("The following error occured: " + msg + " " + code);
                } //error

            });

        });




    </script>


</head>
```

Comment: important to realize that `document.ready` has already occured in main page, so code from ajax will fire immediately. It won't wait for any html that follows it to load

Comment: Have you tried using `$.mobile.changePage()` to navigate between the pages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Reason

When jQuery Mobile loads pages after the initial one (with ajax), it will only load its BODY content, which means any js or css file initialized in HEAD (and if it is not initialized in first loaded HTML) will be disregarded. So all your custom js code will never be executed.

## Solution

#### Move all of your js code into the first HTML file

You should create a new js file, name it whatever you want. Put all of your js code (from every page) into it. Then initialize it in the first HTML file to load.

#### Move your js code into the page BODY

Simply open every page and move its javascript code from HEAD to the BODY. Because of this, javascript code will be loaded into the DOM and executed when page is shown.

## Final thoughts

All of this is described in more details + examples  in my other answer/article: [**Why I have to put all the script to index.html in jquery mobile**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806954/1848600)

You should also think about switching to the jQuery Mobile page events instead of document ready. Document ready usually works correctly but sometimes it will trigger before page is loaded into the DOM. That why jQM page events must be used instead. They will make sure page content is triggered only after page is safely loaded into the DOM. To find out more take a look at this answer/article: [**jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I moved every page's script inside the body tag (before all the elements). the first page works fine, but in the build.htm page it won't recognize my build_crew() function.. and the third page code won't execute. by your second way you mean that I should build functions in an external js file, include the file into my index.htm head. but then where should I call them from if I want them to load with each page load?

Comment: First tell me how do you initialize build_crew() function inside your build.html? If you move them inside a single index.js file then you need to initialize then with jQM page events. Here I made you an example, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8hKe2/