# phonegap 3.5.0 and jquery mobile 1.4.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

In the last few days I am facing always some problem with phonegap and jquery. I need to build phonebook application with list and filter and link on user details. Therefore I have few questions.

1. At first I had problem with getting data from a web server (I used PHP script to return json data and made an ajax request) than I had to configure it to work with cross domain and that went fine ( I am storing data also in the local device database). Is this the right approach?
2. After that I wanted to make a new html page for the user details. Everything went fine until I added new javascript file in this new html page. Javascript didnt work, I dont know for what reason. I even made the basic hello page and included js file and just one line like alert(hello); in it and still nothing. Like all js files are only loaded in index.html and not in any other page. My code for this was (userdetail.js):

   ```
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   var db = null;
   // Cordova is ready
   //
   function onDeviceReady() {
       console.log("opening database");
       db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
       console.log("database");
       //db.transaction(getUser, errorCB);     
       alert("hello");
   }
   ```

   and for html page:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,width=device-width" />
       <title>Hello</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="userPage" data-role="page">    
       <div data-role="content">hallo
                   <div id="userDetail"></div> 
       </div>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userdetail.js"></script> 

   <script type="text/javascript">
       app.initialize();
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   and still didnt get it working. Than I decided, well I will make everything just in one page with javascript. Am I missing something here? I didnt even get the console.log info. I am redirecting the user with this part (links are made with javascript and appended to index.html page in this part):

   ```
       <!DOCTYPE html>

       <html>
       <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
       <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
       <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /> -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
       <title>Hello World</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <div id="userListPage1" data-role="page">   

       <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" style="overflow:hidden;">

           <h1> </h1>
           <a href="#"  class="ui-btn ui-icon-recycle ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-right"></a>

           <!--
           <div id="custom-border-radius">
               <a href="#mypanel" class="ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-left">No text</a>
           </div>
           -->
           <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-nodisc-icon ui-state-persist" data-icon="home" data-theme="a"></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#userListPage2" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-icon="shop" data-theme="a"></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#userListPage3" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-icon="user" data-theme="a"></a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>

       </div>


       <div data-role="content" >
           <ul id="userList1" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">

           </ul>   
       </div>

       <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">

           <h1>Private</h1>
       </div>  


       <!--
       <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-corners="false" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a">
               <ul data-role="listview">
                   <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#" data-rel="close">Close menu</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Accordion</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Ajax Navigation</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#panel-fixed-page2">Autocomplete</a></li> 
               </ul>
           </div>
        -->


       </div>


       <div id="userListPage2" data-role="page">   



        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" style="overflow:hidden;">

           <h1> </h1>
           <a href="#"  class="ui-btn ui-icon-recycle ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-right"></a>

           <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom" >
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#userListPage1" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-icon="home" data-theme="a"></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-nodisc-icon ui-state-persist" data-icon="shop" data-theme="a"></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#userListPage3" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-icon="user" data-theme="a"></a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>

       </div>


       <div data-role="content">
           <ul id="userList2" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">

           </ul>   
       </div>

       <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">

           <h1>Companies</h1>
       </div>  


       </div>

       <div id="userListPage3" data-role="page">   



           <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" style="overflow:hidden;">

           <h1> </h1>
           <a href="#"  class="ui-btn ui-icon-recycle ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-btn-right"></a>

           <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom" >
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="#userListPage1" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-icon="home" data-theme="a"></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#userListPage2" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-icon="shop" data-theme="a"></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn-active ui-nodisc-icon ui-state-persist" data-icon="user" data-theme="a"></a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>

       </div>


       <div data-role="content">
           <ul id="userList3" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">

           </ul>   
       </div>

       <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">

           <h1>Organisations</h1>
       </div>  


   </div>



   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userlist.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       app.initialize();
   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
   ```

   and here is the js that generates userList1 from above

   ```
   function querySuccess(tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length;
   console.log("TELEFONBOOK table: " + len + " rows found.");
   $('#userList1 li').remove();
   $('#userList2 li').remove();
   $('#userList3 li').remove();
   for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
       //append the users to userlist, show the data
       if(results.rows.item(i).typ == "p"){
           $('#userList1').append('<li><a href="user_details.html?id=' + results.rows.item(i).id + '"> ' + results.rows.item(i).nachname + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).vorname + '<p>' + results.rows.item(i).strasse + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).strasse_nr + '</p></a></li>');
       }else if(results.rows.item(i).typ == "f"){
           $('#userList2').append('<li><a href="user_details.html?id=' + results.rows.item(i).id + '"> ' + results.rows.item(i).nachname + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).vorname + '<p>' + results.rows.item(i).strasse + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).strasse_nr + '</p></a></li>');
       }else if(results.rows.item(i).typ == "o"){
           $('#userList3').append('<li><a href="user_details.html?id=' + results.rows.item(i).id + '"> ' + results.rows.item(i).nachname + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).vorname + '<p>' + results.rows.item(i).strasse + ' ' + results.rows.item(i).strasse_nr + '</p></a></li>');
       }


       console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
   }
   $('#userList1:visible').listview('refresh');
   $('#userList2:visible').listview('refresh');
   $('#userList3:visible').listview('refresh');
   }
   ```

   Here is the user_details.html:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,width=device-width" />
   <title>Hello</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userdetails.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       app.initialize();

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="userPage" data-role="page">    

       <div data-role="content">hallo
                   <div id="fullName"></div> 
       </div>

       <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
           <h1>Privat</h1>
       </div>

      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
   ```

   and here is the userdetails.js

   ```
   var id = getUrlVars()["id"];

   // Wait for Cordova to load
   //
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   var db = null;
   // Cordova is ready
   //
   function onDeviceReady() {
       console.log("opening database");
       db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
       console.log("database");
       db.transaction(getUser, errorCB);       
       alert("hello");
   }


   // Query the database
   //
   function getUser(tx) {
       var sql = "SELECT * FROM TELEFONBOOK WHERE id=:id";
       tx.executeSql(sql, [id], getUserSuccess);
   }

   // Query the success callback
   //
   function getUserSuccess(tx, results) {
       var user = results.rows.item(0);

       $('#fullName').text(user.nachname + ' ' + user.vorname);
       alert("hallo");
   }


   // Transaction error callback
   //
   function errorCB(err) {
       alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
   }


   //function to get the id value
   function getUrlVars() {
   alert("test");
   var vars = [], hash;
   var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
   for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
   {
       hash = hashes[i].split('=');
       vars.push(hash[0]);
       vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
   }
       return vars;
   }
   ```
3. After that, my final question. I made in the index.html page listview like this:

   ```
   <div data-role="content">
       <ul id="userList3" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
       </ul>   
   </div>
   ```

   and now I am facing a problem every time I click on the filter field. I get a top border and bottom border white line. For example (notice the white line between two red lines when i click in the filter field):

[image: img]

I dont know is this really normal when using phonegap and jquery mobile to have so many problems. But any help or advice would really help. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

2.After really hard searching and testing, I found the solution here [Pageshow not triggered after changepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082895/pageshow-not-triggered-after-changepage/16083870#16083870)

3.I have managed to find the problem. In the jquery mobile css change the
ui-footer-fixed.ui-fixed-hidden to

```
ui-footer-fixed.ui-fixed-hidden{bottom:-1px;padding-bottom:1px}
```

and same for the header:

```
ui-header-fixed.ui-fixed-hidden{top:-1px;padding-top:1px}
```

Comment: Hi enigmaticus, can you add details for the 2nd point: are you navigating from an index page to your new page? How? Can you add your index page in this case?

Comment: I have added the info, please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Sorry but I still do not understand what you've tried in terms of navigation between your pages, if there is one

Comment: My mistake, it's more clear now. Just can you add the full index.html file to see the added scripts & everything. Last month when I made a single page app with JQM 1.4.2 (using Cordova 3.3 or 3.4, don't remember), the child pages contains only a body, all the scripts were loaded by the index page

Comment: Edited the post. Now I added the full index.html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the edits. For the 2nd point, here are some advices:

The code inside your `userdetail.js` will only be fired on real terminal, not when debugging on a browser on a desktop computer, due to the `deviceready` event which is not thrown by desktop browsers. If you want to simulate this part, you should replace

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`

by

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
} else {
    onDeviceReady();
}
```

in your `userdetail.js` file. (and change the match test to add windws phone userAgent if needed ;-)

---

To clean the mess: put all your scripts at the end of the `head` in your index:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" /> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userdetail.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userlist.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

With this order, you will get the console.log event. Don't forget that localStorage used in userdetails.js will not work on a desktop browser also.

Last (but not least), to populate your listviews, you will have to call your `querySuccess` method from somewhere, I did not see it right now.

---

UPDATE: as you also find, you can also add the scripts in your 2nd page **inside the page div** (see SO [Pageshow not triggered after changepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082895/pageshow-not-triggered-after-changepage/16083870#16083870))

Comment: thank you a lot, i will try this tomorrow and get back to you with the feedback :) and querySuccess is working fine, so I didnt include this part of a code

Comment: and  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userdetail.js"></script>  should be included in another page (user_details.html) which is made specially for the user details. or did i miss something here? I know that this wont work in desktop browser, i am only making in for iOS, Android and Windows phone

Comment: From my previous tests on the subject, with jquery mobile/phonegap, I used single-page-application architecture and include my scripts in the index. In fact with this architecture, JQM is manipulating the DOM (body part) and keeps the called scripts, so it's not necessary to add them once again in the child page

Comment: I have tried this and it is not working. :(  do you have maybe any idea how can i from a list view when user clicks on a link get a new page with user details or something like that? now i thought to have it with the new html page but obviously javascript is not working

Comment: What is not working (as you have several points, I need more info)? How are you testing? For your first tests you should try to implement a list of contact details without using localStorage/database, to handle the navigation first, and incrementally add features.

Comment: I have added now the full user_details.html page and userdetails.js. Is it possible there is something with cordova.js path? since i am not finding it in project folder where index.html is located but in platform/android folder

Comment: Are you building the app or just testing on a computer? We should exchange by chat, but I don't find how to create a chat room..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58327/discussion-between-nicolas-r-and-enigmaticus).