# Partitioning Apache Cordova app in several files

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Typically, a Cordova / jQueryMobile app has a `index.html` file containing many `data-role="page"` pages.

**May I partition the `index.html` file into several parts `part1.html`, `part2.html`...?**

My goal is to **partition a huge DOM into several smaller DOMs** to get loaded on demand.

I did search the Cordova and jQueryMobile documentation sites, but failed to find a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use these things

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
        $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {     
            $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
        }); 
    });
```

OR

```
data-url='about.html'
data-ajax='false'
```

etc.

Learn using these things. Then you'll be able to handle mutiple html files for JQM.

Lets get you started with these following links

[Create Multiple jQuery Mobile Pages and Link them](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/645134/Create-Multiple-jQuery-Mobile-Pages-and-Link-them)

Check the question and also the first answer : [Navigate between three pages in two different files in JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504799/navigate-between-three-pages-in-two-different-files-in-jquery-mobile)

AND this one : [Linking pages](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Comment: Thank you! Hm, my question was kind of trivial. Found a solution minute after my post. But was AFK after that.