# Rails, JQuery Mobile & Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, web-applications

Hi stackoverflow community,

this is my first question on the site after being helped a lot by this one!

I'm building a mobile web application in Ruby On Rails integrating the JQuery Mobile Framework for an existing desktop web application.

I've used Mobvious Gem for the mobile detection (https://github.com/jistr/mobvious) and I'm using respond_to format.mobile to differentiate desktop than mobile view.

**So, here is my problem :**
I've 2 problems but I'm sure they're related.

1. I had to set all my link with the attribute "data-ajax" => "false" to be sure my javascript charged after otherwise I wasn't the case
2. After a redirect_to from a controller or a render or a link "data-rel" => "back"
   the javascript of the page isn't reload.

I would like to know if there is a best practice using Rails and JQuery Mobile with Javascript. 
Also, I would prefer to have only 1 JS file in app/assets/javascript with all my mobile JS content but it doesn't work.

Thank your for your help!

**EDIT :** when I look into firebug, when writing into the console the live event object:

1. first time : console show the object 1 time and javascript run correctly
2. second time : console show the object 2 times and I've an error
   "TypeError: cyclic object value" and javascript doesn't run
3. third time : console show the object 3 times and javascript run
   correctly

**Here is the structure of my mobile's views :**

**My "rails layout" :**

> > !! %html{..html tag content..}
>
> %head
>
> ```
> /render the head with all includes & metatag
>   = render 'head'
> ```
>
> %body
>
> ```
> /render here each page made by the layout _page_mobile.haml
>
>   = yield
> ```

**The _page_mobile.haml file :**

> %div{:id => "#{page_id}", :style => "padding-bottom:0px;", :data =>
>   {:role => "page", :theme => "b"}}
>
> ```
> /Common header bar for all pages  
> %div#headerBar{:class => "main-header", :data => {:role => "header",:theme => "b"}}
>    = render 'header'   
>
> /content of the page   
>  %div.mainContainer{:style => "padding: 0px;", :data => {:role =>"content"}} 
>    = page_content   
>
>  /Common footer bar for all pages   
>  %div#footerBar{:data => {:role => "footer", "tap-toggle" => "false",:theme => "b", :position => "fixed"}}
>     = render 'footer'
> ```
>
> /Insert the javascript of the page
>    = javascript_content

**The "template" of a page rent by the code above  :**

> - @pageId = "id_of_the_page"
>
> - @pageContent = capture do
>       Put here the content of the page
>
> - @pageJS = capture do
>     :javascript
>
> ```
> Put here the javascript for the page
> ```
>
> = render 'page', :page_id => @pageId, :page_content => @pageContent, :javascript_content => @pageJs

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to page with JqueryMobile, it doesn't load the head and meta_tags of the new page, it only pre-loads the body. So, when you place your .js inside the body, after the `data-role = page`. Your javascript will, most-likely, be loaded.

**UPDATE:**

@Gajotres, makes a wonderful answer about the same subject: [Why I have to put all the script to index.html in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800121/why-i-have-to-put-all-the-script-to-index-html-in-jquery-mobile/15806954#15806954)