# jquery mobile <a> onclick javascript function does fire

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile

This button

```
<a href='#' onclick='update_status()' data-role='button' data-icon='check' >update</a>
```

Never fires the JavaScript function on iPhone, however does on my desktop (Chrome, Firefox). I tried to assign a "bind" on `pageinit`, never fires as well.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use multiple HTML pages with your jQM app and do you hold yout javascript inside a HEAD?

Comment: The javascript to fire is in the same page, globally I use several pages.

Comment: I want to know is it placed in HEAD or BODY? This is very important.

Comment: The Javascript is in the HEAD. As said it fires on the desktop but not on the iPhone!

Comment: Let me guess it works if you directly access the file?

Comment: got it, I had to put data-ajax="false" on way to get to get to this page.

Comment: That is an overkill. Read my other answer to understand what is happening: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806954/1848600

Comment: data-ajax="false" or rel="external", both work under Safari and chrome on the iphone. When I put the link on the Home Screen this provokes that Safari comes back and wants to show the page ! you can put the javascript in the HEAD or BODY, it will never fire without the external force link.