# photoswipe error when putting site online

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I have the following site: http://kenya.magicblue.es/index.html

when you click gallery, you can see the photoswipe like this:

[image]

then i do F5 and it works fine and place the pictures properly.

it is doing the same in all browsers and mobile devices and I don't understand why...

anyone has any tip that can help me to fix this error?

Comment: There seems to be an error with the chache manifest `Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (-1) http://kenya.magicblue.es/cache.manifest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code.

You are using multiple HTML pages and jQuery mobile has a [**special way of handling them**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806954/1848600). Basically only first page is fully loaded into the DOM with its BODY and HEAD. And only BODY is loaded in other pages. That is why your gallery is not working. It initialization js is in gallery.html HEAD, same HEAD that was discarded. When you reload your page BODY and HEAD is loaded into the DOM and gallery is working correctly.

If you want to solve this:

1. Put your javascript into page BODY
2. Initialize all of your javascript in your first page
3. Use rel="external" when switching between pages, unfortunately yo will lose transition effects.

Comment: Great thanks so much for your help! it is working now, i added not only the JS into the head of the index, also the css that photoswipe is using.