# Background color of body using CSS not reflecting on html page

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, background, marionette

I am trying to change background color of my html page but its not reflecting. I am using **jquerymobile, marionette** for my pages. In my css i have written

```
body {
background-color:rgb(44,2,4);
}
```

even i had tried

```
html, body {
background-color:rgb(44,2,4);
}
```

What happens is the background color is being set, but i can see on html page just for a flash when the pages loads but after that the default jquerymobile theme gets set.
Can anyone please help me with the solution? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with jQuery Mobile you must change class **`.ui-page`** if you want to change background color. Even if you change body background with !important it will still stay hidden because class .ui-page acts as an overlay over whole page.

Even more it must be done with overriding, like this:

```
.ui-page {
    background:rgb(44,2,4) !important;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6wD7v/

**EDIT :**

Found it. You are also using a panel which uses additional overlay div over **.ui-page**.

This CSS will work now:

```
.ui-page, .ui-panel-content-wrap {
    background:rgb(44,2,4) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you please tell me how can i change the .ui-page to change background, because after just writing the code you specified above its still not working. @Gajotres

Comment: Check it now, it should be .ui-page, or copy css from my example.

Comment: Tried with **.ui-page** also, but still not working :( @Gajotres

Comment: Where have you put your CSS? Is it in some exterlan CSS file or a part of HTML file?

Comment: Its in an external custom.css file. But i have checked the file get's loaded in the head tag properly. Should i check something else? @Gajotres

Comment: This could be it. Read my other answer and check if this could be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800121/why-i-have-to-put-all-the-script-to-index-html-in-jquery-mobile/15806954#15806954

Comment: If this HTML file is not your first/original HTML file then this will not work. When jQuery Mobile loads other files into a DOM it discards HEAD content and it loads ONLY page div.

Comment: But this is my first html page and still its not working. @Gajotres

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. You can see from my example that it works. Unfortunately I cant see your project to tell you were your current problem is. If you can, mail me your project, or part of it and I will check it.

Comment: You can check my project over [here](https://github.com/rachnakhokhar/VIBE_JRM_Framework.git) Please advice. @Gajotres

Comment: You can find my common.css in assets/www/assets/css/common.css and the class in which i am loading required css is at below path assets / www / scripts / utils / load_css.js @Gajotres

Comment: Check it now, I have tested it on your project.

Comment: I didn't commit anything, I have added new content to my answer. Take a look.