# Not working untill refresh it manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have an issue, I've been searching but nothing give best answers. 
My apps using jquery mobile **not load any of my script in javascript**
except i **refresh it first manually** 
even i try to refresh it using script, i can't
because it **can't load the script**. 
Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**
I use **rel="external"** and it's just work great 
I think I should understand more about AJAX

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @SimonAdcock I already edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How jQuery Mobile handles page changes

To understand this situation you need to understand how jQuery Mobile works. It uses ajax to load other pages.

First page is loaded normally. Its **`HEAD`** and **`BODY`** is loaded into the **`DOM`**, and they are there to await other content. When second page is loaded, **only** its **`BODY`** content is loaded into the **`DOM`**.

Here's an official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Unfortunately you are not going to find this described in their documentation. Ether they think this is a common knowledge or they forgot to describe this like my other topics. (jQuery Mobile documentation is big but lacking many things).

## Solutions:

- In your second page, and every other page, move your **`SCRIPT`** tag into the **`BODY`** content, like this:
- Move all of your javascript into the original first HTML. Collect everything and put it inside a single js file, into a **`HEAD`**. Initialize it after jQuery Mobile has been loaded.
- Use **rel="external"** in your buttons and every elements you are using to change page. Because of it ajax is not going to be used for page loading and your jQuery Mobile app will behave like a normal web application.

## More informations

More information with working examples can be found in my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)** or even **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800121/why-i-have-to-put-all-the-script-to-index-html-in-jquery-mobile/15806954#15806954)**.

Comment: rel="external" work great. thanks